# Perl <TMPL_LOOP> issue

Tags: arrays, perl, templates, hash, dbi

I am working on a Perl script, but I am having an issue I can't really overcome. Here is my code:

```
my @rowses = ();


while ( @list = $sth->fetchrow_array())
{
    %row = ();

    if($list[30] == 1) 
      %row = (
            cod_cliente => $list[1],
            rag_soc => $list[2], 
            p_iva => $list[11],
            IDanagrafica => $list[0],
            tabella => $tab,
            IDanagraficaE => $list[0],
            tabellaE => $tab,
            checkbox => "checked",
            );
    $LOL = \%row;
    print $cgi->p($LOL);
}
else
{
    %row = (
            cod_cliente => $list[1],
            rag_soc => $list[2], 
            p_iva => $list[11],
            IDanagrafica => $list[0],
            tabella => $tab,
            IDanagraficaE => $list[0],
            tabellaE => $tab,
            checkbox => "",
            );
    $LOL = \%row;
    print $cgi->p($LOL);
}

push (@rowses, \%row);
}

 $template->param(table => \@rowses);   
$template->param(tab => $tab);
```

When I try to print, for debugging, the reference to a row ($LOL), it prints nothing, and when I print the reference at @rowses, it is an array full of all the same hash, the last one the fetched by from the statement.

The weird is, if I print a hash row per time, without referencing it, it prints them well, and all of them.

I am doing that for passing the array reference, containing all the hashes, to a TMPL_LOOP, and print them; but it print a long list of only the last row fetched.

Thanks in advance to everyone who will help me.

Comment: Are you missing a curly brace after if($list[30] == 1)  ?

Comment: You could simplify that conditional by saying something like:  `%row = (cod_cliente => ..., tabellaE => $tab); $row{checkbox} = ($list[30] == 1 ? "checked" : "");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `%row` is the same variable for each iteration of the while loop. You store just the reference to it in `@rowses`, which means if you change `%row`, all the references point to the changed hash. You should define a new `%row` for each iteration of the loop, e.g. by using

```
my %row;
```

indead of

```
%row = ();
```

Why $LOL is not printed: If the first argument to `p` is a hash reference, it is interpreted as the attributes of the `<p>`.

Comment: @Snowzurfer: Regarding `my %row` vs. `%row`, you are using `use strict` and `use warnings`, right?

Comment: @chepner: Nope, I was not. I had this issue while trying to correct the code made from a another person; this is why I am having some trouble, as I am not the one who wrote this. The company I am working for gave me this task.

Comment: @choroba: I will try what you have suggested me, and I'll let you know

Comment: @choroba: I have written as you have suggested, and it worked. Thanks a lot, you've been very helpful to me :D